# Scaling a Heroku dyno from within the script

Tags: python, heroku

I'm running a spider using a worker dyno, and everything is working. It's great, but Heroku gets confused whenever the spider is finished. It prints the following logs and starts up the app again because it thinks the app crashed.

```
app[worker.1]: 2020-11-23 00:04:10 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python realscraper.py`
```

So how do I tell the Heroku dyno that when the spider closes, it should just scale down to 0? I don't want it to crash and keep trying to restart.

Comment: please add the code as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By modifying [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/automatically-scale-heroku-dynos/) (there are some errors or depreciated stuff in it) I was able to create a `scale` function within the `close_spider` function of my pipeline. It will automatically scale the dyno to zero when my spider closes, so Heroku can't run the script again afterwards.

```
APP = "herokuappname" ## your app name
KEY = "yourapikey" ## your Heroku API key
PROCESS = "worker" ## any type of dyno process should work here
HEADERS = {
    'Accept': "application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3",
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + KEY,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

class MyPipeline:
    ## up here are the __init__ and process_item definitions, omitted for clarity

    def close_spider(self, spider):

        def scale(size):
            payload = {'quantity': size} ## size is the number of dynos to scale to
            json_payload = json.dumps(payload)
            url = "https://api.heroku.com/apps/" + APP + "/formation/" + PROCESS
            try:
                result = requests.patch(url, headers=HEADERS, data=json_payload)
            except:
                print("Running scale function didn't work lol")
                return None
            if result.status_code == 200:
                return "Success!"
            else:
                return "Failure"

        print('Scaling out ... Closing app...')
        print(scale(0))
        
        return
```

Apparently I [wasn't the only one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41112226/heroku-process-exits-with-status-0-but-its-dyno-still-crashes) looking for a similar solution to this. Heroku Docs don't make it clear enough that you can close dynos from a script using the API.